# Writing if/then Statements for Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, conditional

For some reason I *cannot* get this code to work in the Field Calculator of ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. I'm trying to use the Python parser to populate the field "SHAP_CLAS" with multiple conditional statements based on "AREA_LA" and "AREA_PERI_SQR".

[image]

The code I've tried so far is:

```py
def calc(AREA_LA, AREA_PERI_SQR):
   if (AREA_LA =< 100 and AREA_PERI_SQR =< 0.65):
       return 2
   elif (AREA_LA =< 100 and AREA_PERI_SQR > 0.65):
       return 1
   elif (100 < AREA_LA < 500 and AREA_PERI_SQR =< 0.45):
       return 2
   elif (100 < AREA_LA < 500 and AREA_PERI_SQR > 0.45):
       return 1
   else:
       return 3
```

...and...

```
calc(!SHAP_CLAS!)
```

...in the box below the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, also call field calculator on the field you want to change ("SHAP_CLAS" for you):

```
def calc(AREA_LA, AREA_PERI_SQR): ##also change =< to <=
   if (AREA_LA =< 100 and AREA_PERI_SQR =< 0.65): 
       return 2
   elif (AREA_LA =< 100 and AREA_PERI_SQR > 0.65):
       return 1
   elif (100 < AREA_LA < 500 and AREA_PERI_SQR =< 0.45):
       return 2
   elif (100 < AREA_LA < 500 and AREA_PERI_SQR > 0.45):
       return 1
   else:
       return 3
```

and the change is here:
(you are using method with 2 field, but then, you are providing only one field to the method)

```
calc(!AREA_LA!, !AREA_PERI_SQR!)
```

Basically the code is:

```
def method(field1, field2, fieldX):
    '''do something'''
    return value
```

and call:

```
method(!field1!,!field2!,!fieldX!)
```

There are some examples half way through at this page:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm

Answer (score 1):

You've not told us what the error message you're receiving is, but from looking at your code I can see you're not using the correct operator for 'Less Than or Equal To'.

You've used:`=<`
When it should be: `<=`

Correcting that should hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: It will not work. Because she is calling a method with two attributes with only one provided (and the wrong one also). But you are right about the operator.

Comment: You are right about the operator. With @JanDoležal's code and '<=' it works, thank you!